# getJSON doesnt call webAPI method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

Im new on mvc 4 and webAPI and Im developing my first application on it.It is single page application and using Knockoutjs.I use this walkthrough  https://github.com/geersch/KnockoutSpa/
every thing is fine with my webAPI method and it return correct value when I call method with Fiddler.But it never called when I use it from getJson() method.Here is my HTML:

```
    <table id="nqsales" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: viewModel.nqsales">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: a"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: b"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: c"></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    viewModel.loadNqsales();
});

var viewModel = {
    nqsales: ko.observableArray([]),

    loadNqsales: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON(
            '@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "NQSale" })',
    function (nqsales) {
        self.nqsales.removeAll();
        $.each(nqsales, function (index, item) {
            self.nqsales.push(new nqsale(item));
        });
    }
);
    }
};

function nqsale(nqsale) {
    this.expenceFormNo = ko.observable(nqsale.a);
    this.orderNo = ko.observable(nqsale.b);
    this.date = ko.observable(nqsale.c);
}
```

WebAPIController

```
    // GET api/NQSale
    public IEnumerable<NQSaleDto> GetNQSales()
    {
        //return db.NQSales.AsEnumerable();
        return db.NQSales
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(nqlist => new NQSaleDto(nqlist));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Url construction of

> @Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller =
>   "NQSale" })

should generate a URL of '/api/NQSale' this means that your controller should be the following:

```
//The controller name relates to the route
    public class NQSaleController : ApiController
{
// The action name relates to the HttpVerb
    public IEnumerable<NQSaleDto> Get()
    {
        //return db.NQSales.AsEnumerable();
        return db.NQSales
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(nqlist => new NQSaleDto(nqlist));

    }
}
```

By default, the routing for API is that the name of the controller (NQSaleController) relates to the path and the name of the Action (Get) relates to the HttpVerb.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your Url is not being generated correctly. If the Javascript in the View currently or in a seperate file ? @Url only works if its in the view.

Comment: @Url is in View and it seems generate correctly.its what I see in firebug:
loadNqsales: function () {
var self = this;
$.getJSON(
'/api/NQSale',
function (nqsales) {
self.nqsales.removeAll();
$.each(nqsales, function (index, item) {
self.nqsales.push(new nqsale(item));
});
}